# How to get data in final promise chain from nested promises

Tags: javascript, async-await

So i'm calling function `fetchTaskLeads`. Inside of it, im returning array of promises. But this array of promises, for each promise have nested array of promises, so i want to get data in it.

The problem is, that i'm having `undefined` for last `.then` block for my `parsedLeadsWithContacts`. Why is that happens?

```
const test = fetchTaskLeads(leads)

const fetchTaskLeads = (leads) => {
  if (!isEmpty(leads)) {
    const parsedLeads = []

    return Promise.all(leads.map((l) => db.collection('leads').doc(l).get()))
      .then((fetchedLeads) => {
        parsedLeads = fetchedLeads.map((l) => ({ leadId: l.id, ...l.data() }))

        return Promise.all(parsedLeads.map((pl) => fetchTaskContacts([pl.contact.cardId])))
      })
      .then((parsedLeadsWithContacts) =>
        parsedLeads.map((pl, index) => ({ leadId: pl.leadId, ...parsedLeadsWithContacts[index][0] })),
      )
  }
  return []
}
```

Comment: First thing I can see, is that `parsedLeads` should be `let` since you're re-assigning it

Comment: In addition to WinterIsComing's comment, you don't return anything from the last `.then()` - so the resolved value will always be `undefined`

Comment: @RandyCasburn Doesn't `parsedLeads.map` return an array?

Comment: it should - but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think the last section should be:

```js
      ...
      .then((parsedLeadsWithContacts) => {
        // add return keyword, and rewrite with full braces to see what is going on:
        return parsedLeads.map((pl, index) => ({
          leadId: pl.leadId,
          ...parsedLeadsWithContacts[index][0]
        })) //, and take off the ending comma
      })
```